# html form layout arrangement

Tags: html, css, forms, textarea

I was trying to create a registration form and I encountered a problem.[`jsfiddlehere`](https://jsfiddle.net/jc040993/mvbxacjq/)
Output is as shown in image below[image]
As shown in the image I want the address to be at the top of the line as indicated without using style position relative or absolute. Is it possible to fix that with margin or padding. And the other thing is why the address text is appearing in the bottom, doesnt it be at the top by default? Is it because of textarea?
Thanks in advance

Comment: CSS #address span{
  vertical-align:top;
}

Comment: and i also want to know how to arrange a child div(height:10px) inside a parent div(height:100px) top, center or bottom. can we use this vertical-align to make it out or vertical-align only works for text only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To align verticaly 2 inline-block elements, you can use `vertical-align`.
In your case:

```
.container span {
    padding-left: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30%;

    /* Add vertical alignment */
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tzi/0u0ozcm4/).

Comment: Ty bro for the reply. is the reason behind this is due the default value of vertical-align is bottom? and can you check my code and tell me the effective way of designing the layout. Am I doing the effective way or do I need to improve?

Comment: and i also want to know how to arrange a child div(height:10px) inside a parent div(height:100px) top, center or bottom. can we use this vertical-align to make it out or vertical-align only works for text only?

Comment: Using `inline-block` element to render a label and an input is pretty OK. But it could be tricky for the responsive.

Comment: To align a child inside a parent, you can not use `vertical-align`. This property only works between two children that have an inline flow. You probably could use `position: absolute` on the children and `position: relative` on the parent for an easy positionning (ex: https://jsfiddle.net/tzi/22rkx7uo/). But be careful, you will lost the element flow.

Comment: why did you say that inline-block is tricky for responsive?
I understood about vertical-align which works between inline elements. So it cant be used to place a div inside another div at top, center or bottom. Is there any other way without using position because position sometimes gives problems to me(it overlaps with other elements) @tzi

Comment: You could use two different CSS modules for layout: table or flex. Here is an example using table layout (compatible IE8+) https://jsfiddle.net/tzi/tkcgoz5n/

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS...

```
#address span{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Ty bro for the reply. is the reason behind this is due the default value of vertical-align is bottom? and can you check my code and tell me the effective way of designing the layout. Am I doing the effective way or do I need to improve?

Answer (score 1):

Write the html like this

```
<span> Address <textarea cols="5" rows="10"></textarea></span>
```

Add this to your  css

```
span textarea {vertical-align:top;}
```

This code should keep the label at the top, you will then need to align your texarea to the other text fields